# Is nowhere a correct word to use in the sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

Is it a correct sentence if I say

> He yelled at me out of ***nowhere***?

The intention is to convey that someone started yelling at me suddenly and there
didn't seem to be anything understandable in the current situation which would justify
yelling. Is this word ***nowhere*** correct to use or is there a better way to convey the
same?

Comment: Yes. If that's the meaning, then that's how many would say it. Another way would be to say, "He yelled at me out of the blue."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "out of nowhere" is commonly used in that meaning.